# Is it "historical-philosophical" or "historico-philosophical"?

Tags: hyphenation

I was wondering what are the rules for writing hyphenated adjectives, specially those composed by words ending in "-al" such as "historical" and "philosophical".

I have seen both "historical-philosophical" and "historico-philosophical". With respect to these terms: Is one of those right or recommended, or can I freely use both? Are there different recommendations according to the dialect (UK, Canada, USA)? Which term would be the original one?

Comment: Shakespearean precedent exists: "pastoral-comical, historical-pastoral,
tragical-historical, tragical-comical-historical-pastoral" *(Hamlet* 2.2)--but that litany serves to confirm that the speaker (Polonius) is a buffoon, so evoking that precedent might be opening oneself to ridicule.

Comment: Why do you want to use a hyphen? Just put the words together.